# Testing value of set-only property using only Moq

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I have a simple class that sets a field in the constructor, and the matching property is read-only.

```
public class COMAssembly : ICOMAssembly
{
    private List<string> properties = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Properties
    {
        get { return properties; }
    }

    ...
}
```

I have these test classes using MSpec and Moq:

```
using Machine.Specifications;
using Moq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using It = Machine.Specifications.It;

public class MSPEC_With_a_COM_Assembly
{
    protected static Mock<ICOMAssembly> _mockCOMAssembly;
    protected static List<string> _listOfStrings;

    Establish context = () =>
       {
           _mockCOMAssembly = new Mock<ICOMAssembly>(MockBehavior.Loose);
           _mockCOMAssembly.DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock;
           _mockCOMAssembly.SetupAllProperties();
           _mockCOMAssembly.SetupProperty(m => m.Properties, new List<string>() { "Prop1", "Prop2" });
       };
}

[Subject(typeof(MSPEC_With_a_COM_Assembly), "With a COM Assembly")]
public class When_asking_for_a_list_of_properties_and_assembly_has_properties : MSPEC_With_a_COM_Assembly
{
    Because of = () =>
      {
          _listOfStrings = _mockCOMAssembly.Object.Properties;
      };

    It Should_return_a_list_with_values = () =>
        {
            //TODO:  Verify that the Count property of _listOfStrings/_mockCOMAssembly.Object.Properties is greater than zero.
        };
}
```

I've reviewed many forums, Moq tutorials, etc. and can't find an answer to how to do this using only Moq.  I do not want to use NUnit.  I have other tests that pass that verify that _listOfStrings  is not null and the get on the property works fine.  I'm new to practicing MSpec/Moq/Unit Testing, though I've read a lot on the topics so far.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to achieve here? Usually you would create your `Mock<ICOMAssembly>` to supply as a dependancy to a class which needs an `ICOMAssembly` without having to use the `COMAssembly` class. You seem to be trying to verify the behaviour of the Mock from what I can gather?!

Comment: Moq isn't a testing library by itself; it's meant to be a supplement to one. As pointed out by the commenter above, you wouldn't normally test the mock itself - are you sure that you understand what a mocking library is for? (Mocking is a somewhat advanced testing concept that you shouldn't start looking into until you've mastered regular unit testing of simple classes without dependencies.)

Comment: You haven't actually said what the problem is. other than that, Trevor's comment is correct; you appear to be unit testing a mock, which is a pointless exercise.

Comment: So I have to use NUnit.  I'm okay with that.

I was mocking the COM Assembly because I could be using any of several COM Assemblies.  I created a stub COM Assembly for testing with instead.  Probably the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: You are simply testing the mock here. And I can't see any value in that